# Remove element from state array without mutating it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state in my class component:

```
this.state = {
  todos: [ {0: "Wake up"}, {1: "Have breakfast"}, {2, "Have lunch}, ... ]
}
```

How can I remove an specific element from `todos` without mutating the array itself? I then want to set `todos` to a new array without that element.

Any help is appreciated as I am new to React!

Comment: either you mutate or get a new object. there is no deleting without mutating.

Comment: ```this.setState(state=> state.filter(item=> !item.0)```

make use of filter to remove a particular element from an array.